# Ionic Angular - How to replace Special Characters with a Prefix for URI

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Im new to Ionic and I have taken up a project from a girl who has recently left my work.
I have received a defect that when the user types in “N/A” to search for an order it breaks the URI when searching. A co-developer has suggested that replacing the “/” with “%2F” will fix this in the URI.

For a long term fix I would like to be able to read what the user has entered and if it contains any special characters then replace it with this prefix?

Here is some code I have:

```
   async getOrder() {
   if ( this.searchValue.length < 1) {
  console.log('search is empty');
  this.alertService.emptyInput();
} else {
    /**
     * Setup loading controller
     */
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Searching..'
    });
    await loading.present();

          // Get access token from storage
     this.storage.get(ACCESS_TOKEN).then((token) => {
       console.log('token from storage: ', token);

       if (this.searchValue === 'N/A') {
         this.searchValue = 'N%2FA';
       }
       const urlOrderNo = this.apiUrl + 'ordersearch/' + this.searchValue;
```

So for example ive added the = 'N/A' but I also need to check the string each time as order numbers may contain special characters also.

Would anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use any of the following methods:
1. `escape()` This method will not encode the following `@/+`
2. `encodeURIComponent()` This method will not encode the following `~!()'`

I prefer the second method `encodeURIComponent()`
So replace

```
if (this.searchValue === 'N/A') {
  this.searchValue = 'N%2FA';
}
const urlOrderNo = this.apiUrl + 'ordersearch/' + this.searchValue;
```

with

```
const urlOrderNo = this.apiUrl + 'ordersearch/' + encodeURIComponent(this.searchValue);
```

Comment: encodeURIComponent(this.password) worked for me! thanks :)